Usage of そこまでは by itself
The context is the following: money have been stolen and the group is trying to figure what to do and if they can recover. The convo is a back and forth between the boss and one underling.

つっても回収できるのか？
どうかしら…山科さん、お金結構な額貰ってたみたいなんだけどもう全部ないって言うのよ
ない、ですか。ブランドものとか現物もない？
そこまでは。でも、調査班の話だとそんな感じに聞こえたわ

I understand the character wonders if they'll be able to recover the money stolen
to which the boss replies  "she said there is nothing left"
Then the character asks if there are things like "ブランドもの" to which the character replies...
"そこまでは。でも、調査班の話だとそんな感じに聞こえたわ"
Judging by the investigation team's talk, it seemed the case, phrasing.
I'm stumbled on how to take "そこまでは" here? I assume it's either "Up to this point" or maybe "we haven't gotten to that point yet"?

It seems there left out something like

そこまでは（知らない・把握していない・聞いていない）

Strictly speaking, そこまで does not directly refers to the information whether 山科さん has ブランドとかの現物 or not. Instead, そこまで "to that extent, go that far" refers to their knowledge does not extend "to that extent (possibly of quantity or how detailed the information is)".
